# How can I maintain two active asyncio streams without a TimeoutError?

Tags: python, asynchronous, networking, async-await, python-3.6

I'm trying to use asyncio to manage connections in a p2p networking application. I am trying to maintain a large number (~300) of connections using asyncio streams.

I'm using python3.6 and it hangs and times out on asyncio.open_connection(...) each time.

```py
async def example():
    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection(ip, port) 
    writer.write(handshake)
    await writer.drain()
    response = await reader.read(RESP_SIZE)
    errcode, results = await worker(reader, writer, workerdata)

    # This is the line it hangs and times out on
    reader2, writer2 = await asyncio.open_connection(ip2, port2)
    # Second, identical handshake sequence here
    writer2.write(handshake)
    await writer2.drain()
    response = await reader2.read(RESP_SIZE)
    errcode, results = await worker(reader2, writer2, workerdata2)


def main():

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(example())
    loop.close()
```

A trivial example works for a single connection, but once I try to perform a handshake/open a second connection it hangs and I receive

```
TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connect call failed
```

Is it possible to have multiple connections to different client ip/port pairs at the same time using asyncio streams? Is there a different async library that's more appropriate for this?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue while replacing the worker by a sleep code. Using Python 3.7

Answer (score 0):

It hangs because the worker deadlocks waiting for some foreign message.
Piece of advise, always use timeouts.